# noexcept operator compile-time check

Tags: c++, noexcept

In bellow code I'm trying to use conditional exception specification for functions but compile fails, although if used outside function it works just fine.

```
void may_throw();

// ERROR: expression must have bool type or be convertible to bool
void check () noexcept(may_throw());

int main()
{
    // works just fine!
    std::cout << noexcept(may_throw());
}
```

The question is how to check if function throws without changing function prototype to conditionally specify `noexcept`?

I can't change function prototype because the point is to check if function throws not if it should return true or false.

**EDIT**

*I'm trying to make fun of the `noexcept` but it looks like it's not working for* macros.

```
#include <iostream>

#if 0
#define ASDF(...) (void)0
#else
#define ASDF(...) throw 1
#endif

void check() noexcept(noexcept(ASDF()))
{
    // wrong!
    // std::cout << noexcept(noexcept(ASDF()));

    // edit: it should be this, and it works.
    // (tnx: StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica)
    std::cout << noexcept(ASDF());
    ASDF(0);
}

int main()
{
    check();
}
```

Comment: `noexcept( noexcept( may_throw() ) )`

Comment: For your edit, what do you mean *not working*?

Comment: I mean that `check()` function will be declared as `noexcept` but it actually throws since it calls `ASDF()` which will throw.

Comment: Your print check is flawed. It should be `std::cout << noexcept(ASDF());`. In your edit you apply the operator twice. The outer invocation is applied to the constant `0`, which is of course a non-throwing expression.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica uh, my mistake, it looks like I still didn't learn from given answers! I'll edit my post..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given `void check () noexcept(may_throw());`, [noexcept specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec) expects an expression convertible to `bool`, while `may_throw()` returns `void` and can't convert to `bool`.

You should apply [noexcept operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept) on `may_throw()` and specify it to noexcept specifier. i.e.

```
// whether check is declared noexcept depends on if the expression
// may_throw() will throw any exceptions
void check () noexcept(noexcept(may_throw()));
//            ^^^^^^^^          -> specifies whether check could throw exceptions 
//                     ^^^^^^^^ -> performs a compile-time check that returns true if may_throw() is declared to not throw any exceptions, and false if not.
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do it is:

```
noexcept( noexcept( may_throw() ) )
```

As to why, the first `noexcept` is defined as `noexcept-specifier`. This is used to tell whether a function is `noexcept` or not. It has the form (from `[except.spec]`):

```
noexcept-specifier:
    noexcept ( constant-expression )
    noexcept
    throw ( )
```

The second, is the `noexcept-operator`: *The noexcept operator determines whether the evaluation of its operand, which is an unevaluated operand
(8.2), can throw an exception (18.1).* from `[expr.unary.noexcept]`